# Enable Deep Linking for an Android app

Tags: android, deep-linking

Recently I built an Android app that consume data through JSON from a back-end. There is no public/front zone, it's only back-end. Moreover I built a showcase-website just to let people know the app exists.
Back-end and Showcase-Webiste reside at two different URLs. In the developer console I enabled the app indexing and the showcase-website is the one I set.

I'd like to add deep linking but I can't figure out how to configure the intent-filter.

For example, suppose my showcase-website URL is this:
http://nolimitsworld.com/

How should I configure the data section of the intent-filter? the host parameter should be?

Answer (score 0):

The question in your subject line is misleading. You do have a public web site, and that's your showcase web site. Use that showcase web site for your intent filter. The backend url only gets called from your android app anyway, so no one needs to know that one but you.

If you still need help figuring it out, please remove the api url from your question, and just show us the url to your showcase web site instead (and only register that one with google).

Now if your other concern is that you wish to index your application without going through any web site at all since most people wouldn't recognize the domain name of your web site anyway, then there is actually no need to do deeping linking and app indexing through google.

You could just get away with indexing the content of your app with a search provider and launching your app with an explicit intent. Google doesn't even need to get involved if you do that.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading title (it denotes my confusion about it).
I edited the question because I can't still figure out how to do it. What I don't understand how make the app respond to an intent to load the activity for an accommodation (for example) with id = 2

Comment: Take a look at this presentation, slide 8 https://speakerdeck.com/juandg/app-indexing-blurring-the-lines-between-your-website-and-app I'm not sure why there is a dot in the pathpattern, personally I would have only tried *, but you may want to try doing it their way.

Comment: Thanks for the link Stephan ;) but I still don't understand how to configure the data section. Mainly because I don't have an URL like tho one showed in the presentation (Slide 6) because I don't have a public website that shows the information like in the app. Or it's better to say, I've got an URL like that, but that's the back-end.

Comment: Oh I see. You might be right. Deep linking and app indexing may not be for you then.

Comment: Do use a Search Provider then. This component was introduced at Android 3.0. For a Google TV for instance (which is Android based), that's what the Netflix Android app used to make its television shows and movies searchable and openable directly from a google search. It's the precursor to the app indexing that Google does now, and it doesn't require a web site at all.

Comment: Stephan, that sounds nice! I'll look into that ;) It seems what I'm looking for